# Binary to Decimal using Stack in C

Tags: c, binary, stack, decimal

Code for converting binary to decimal using stack in C.
I have used the stack to store the sum after convertion and popped out only top element from stack that contains the sum.
Please suggest any optimization.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define MAX 100
int stack[MAX];
int top=-1;
int num;
void push();
void pop();
main()
{
    printf("Enter the binary number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    push();
    pop();
}
void push()
{
    int rem;
    
        int dec_value = 0;
        int base = 1;
        int temp = num;
        while(temp)
        {
            int last_digit = temp % 10;
            temp = temp / 10;
            dec_value += last_digit * base;
            base = base * 2;
                
        if(top>=MAX)
        {
            printf("\nSTACK OVERFLOW!");
        }
        else
        {
            top++;
            stack[top]=dec_value;
        }
    }
}
void pop()
{
    int i;
    printf("Its decimal form: ");
    printf("%d",stack[top]);
    if(top<0)
    {
        printf("\nStack is empty!");
    }
}
```

Comment: If your code is working and you want feedback on it then posting over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be more appropriate.

Comment: Also, please note that C and C++ are different languages so you should only reference and tag the language you are actually required to code in. It matters as the best implementation may be different for the two languages.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for the suggestion, I will make the changes. Thanks for helping me. This is my first post on stackoverflow.

Comment: Is there a reason to read the binary string as a decimal number? By doing this, you are limited to numbers up to 1023 (see why?). A more convenient approach would be to read a string of digits. And the decimal division/modulus would be unnecessary then. The stack isn't very useful either.

Comment: Not a suggestion for optimisation, but the abuse of global variables is terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion:

- Read a string of binary digits: this allows for up to 32 binary digits when converting to a 32-bit unsigned integer, instead of only 10 binary digits if you read an int.
- Do the conversion without a stack: you only need to shift while you are looping through the string.

Here is a possibility. Note that the input is not checked thoroughly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define N 33

int main(void) {
    char bits[N];
    char *c;
    uint32_t n = 0;
    
    fgets(bits, N, stdin);
    for (c = &bits[0]; *c != '\n' && *c != 0; c++) {
        n = (n << 1) | (*c == '1');
    }
    printf("%u\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```